# How do they do real time website notifications?

Tags: frontend

So on a site like, say, stack overflow parts of the page update when things happen like your reputation increase.  How do they do that lol?  Does a script check from time to time or is it a push notification somehow?

Comment: web sockets, most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 2 years ago stackexchange started using web sockets as stated here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox

If you take a look at the stackoverflow site source you will see that a JavaScript function subscribes to a web socket server.

There are many different approaches to that technology now. Microsoft for example introduced SignalR (http://signalr.net/) which degrades gracefully to older browser too by switching to other technologies where sockets don't work like long polling (asking every X seconds if changes are available).

You as a Python guy would probably start looking at something like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets/1.0

Have fun with web sockets!

Comment: Thanks, always love to have another path to track down ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I didn't want to use web sockets, I would do it like this:

- Have the server maintain a queue of notifications for a session or user or whatever context you want.
- Have a URL for fetching such notifications.
- When a client tries to `GET` that URL, and there are notifications available in the queue, return them immediately.
- Otherwise, have the HTTP connection block until there are notifications queued.
- On the client, side, then; simply try to `GET` the notification URL over and over again. Normally, the connection will sit blocking for data to read, but I don't see that this should be a problem.

I would think this should be easier to implement on the server side than web sockets are, since the HTTP server doesn't have to support any special HTTP extensions. On the other hand, depending on the HTTP server you're using, each such open connection may be using a thread or other system resource that you want to use sparingly.